# Transitioning between views: translation between segues and code

Tags: view, segue

In my storyboard I have 2 VCs: VC1 is a login page and VC2 is the home of my application after the user is logged.

1) the best way to change from one view to another is by using a modal segue? Is this correct?

Second, I would like to know how the segues in my storyboard are "translated" into code?
I have segues of 2 types: modal and push.

I've been using `performSegueWithIdentifier` method in my code, but now I would like to know what happens behind this method.
Is the modal segue translated into `[self presentModalViewController:newVC]` method? 
Is the push segue translated into `[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC]`?

Nothing more really happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question, as always the answer is: it depends on what your needs are.
If you are mainly interested in "discarding" the previous view controller, then yes, a modal segue is the way to go, if you want to let the user navigate through your view controllers, then maybe a navigation controller with push segues are a better way, or even a tab view controller. But again, it really depends on your needs.

As for your second question, have a look at this [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html). 
A segue is an instance of the class UIStoryboardSegue, which keeps a reference to the source view controller and the destination view controller. Before actually performing the segue (the method `perform` that actually perform the transition), the prepareForSegue of the source view controller is called (this gives you the chance of doing some extra set-up before the transition happens), then the actual transition takes place through the method `perform`, where some animation is shown and, based on the type of segue, either `presentViewController:animated:completion:` or `pushViewController:` are called (you can create custom segues by overriding the initialiser method and this `perform` method).